# creating and using hashsum in .iso image

Tags: debian, hashsum

I recently came across sha1sum -c . As the manpage states -

```
-c, --check
              read SHA1 sums from the FILEs and check them
```

Now I know how to generate and use sha1sum from an .iso . For instance,

```
$ sha1sum grml64-full_2014.11.iso 
120bfa48b096691797a73fa2f464c7c71fac1587  grml64-full_2014.11.iso
```

But if I try :-

```
$ sha1sum -c grml64-full_2014.11.iso 
sha1sum: grml64-full_2014.11.iso: no properly formatted SHA1 checksum lines found
```

I even tried :-

```
$ cat sha1sum-grml 
120bfa48b096691797a73fa2f464c7c71fac1587
```

As can be seen it is a single file which has the sha1sum.

If I try the following :-

```
$ sha1sum -c grml64-full_2014.11.iso sha1sum-grml 
sha1sum: grml64-full_2014.11.iso: no properly formatted SHA1 checksum lines found
sha1sum: sha1sum-grml: no properly formatted SHA1 checksum lines found
```

What I tried here was for sha1sum to generate and check the sha1sum with the checksum I have put in a file and compare between the two checksums or something.

Maybe I have mis-understood something, maybe each file in the .iso needs to have its own checksum or something like that ?

I looked up at both the man and the info. and became none the wiser.

Look forward to understanding and a solution.

Comment: `sha1sum -c` is looking for a text file that contains the pre-calculated hash and the location of a file that the hash should be compared with. If you point the command at the .iso file it won't work because the .iso is not a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate the `sha1sum` file,

```
sha1sum myfile >sums
```

Then check with this file,

```
sha1sum -c sums
```